# TypeError: this.props.recipes.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently having some trouble on rendering for the first time an empty array, I think the trouble it is when it runs for the first time and the array is empty; is it anyway to run this render conditionally or maybe a workaround that you guy smight know?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import List, { ListItem, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';

class RecipesList extends Component {
    render() {

    console.log(this.props.recipes)
        return(
            <div>
               <List component="nav">
                    {
                        this.props.recipes.recipes.map(recipe => {
                            return(
                                <ListItem button key={recipe.id}>
                                   <ListItemText>
                                        {recipe.title}
                                    </ListItemText >
                                </ListItem>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </List>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipesList)
```

The recipes array has already been initialized on the reducer as :

```
const defaultState = {
    recipes: []
};
```

Comment: Empty array does not cause this error. This error indicate that `this.state.recipes` is not of array type. What does `console.log(this.props.recipes)` output?

Comment: Bring your reducer code if my answer doesn't work

Comment: I was missing one recipes on line this.props.recipes.recipes, already edited on post. But now it just doesnt renders the list whenever I make the fetch

Comment: This is my reducer code: 

`import { SET_RECIPES } from '../actions';
const defaultState = {
    recipes: []
};

function recipes(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_RECIPES:
            return {...state, recipes};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default recipes;`

Comment: Already fixed everything....was missing  to get my action inside a dispatch function! Thanks a lot guys!